# How to make reference to variables (c++)

Tags: c++

These are global variables:

```
const int MAXROW = 5;
const int MAXCOL = 5;
int A[MAXROW][MAXCOL] = { 0 };
int newarr[MAXROW + 1][MAXCOL + 1] = { 0 };
```

How to declare them in main and to use them in these functions:

```
void case1()
{
for (int r = 0; r < MAXROW; ++r)
    for (int c = 0; c < MAXCOL; ++c) {
        cout << "\n A[" << r << "][" << c << "]= ";
        cin >> A[r][c];

    }

}

void case2()
{

    int max[MAXCOL] = { 0 };

    for (int r = 0; r < MAXROW; ++r) {
        int minr = A[r][0];
    ..............................

    }
void case3()
{
    int negNumber = 0;
    double average = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < 6; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 6; ++c) {
            ..............
if (newarr[r][c] < 0) {
                ++negNumber;
                average += newarr[r][c];
```

I am using do while menu. How can I do it most easily.

Comment: If they are global variables, you don't "declare" them in main - you have already declared them when you said `const int MAXROW = 5;
`, etc. And how do you use them? Well you just -um - use them. Llike you did in case1(). No need to pass them into the methods - they are globally available anywhere in the compilation unit.

Comment: The problem is that i don't want to use them as global.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare local variables in `main()` in the same way you did in `case3()` with `negNumber` and `average`.

Passing variables to another functions is pretty easy. You just need to define input parameters for your function. Like this: `case1( int var1 )`. Now you can use `var1` in your function `case1` and you have to call `case1` with arguments passed in. Like this: `case1( 2 )`.

You can find solution exactly for your case (passsing 2D arrays into funtions) here: [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Read more about funtions in C++ here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4d5ssht.aspx